# GWT get Elements by attribute

Tags: gwt

Which way I can get [GWT Elements](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Element.html) by it's attribute ? I would like to get all of Elements by giving specific attribute and attribute-value.

```
<input type = "text" class = "get-TextBox" nature = "price"/>
<input type = "text" class = "get-TextBox" nature = "address"/>
<input type = "text" class = "get-TextBox" nature = "price"/>
```

above snipet , I want to get input elements by "*nature*" **attribute** and  containing **attribute-values** of "*price*".

> At my actual problem ,they are created by dynamic and not in same panel.Many Elements these having "nature" attribute and "price" attribute value. So , I am using DOM Handler for them.

Eg: [JQuery (get element by attribute)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) , it is my main point to get.

But please don't suggest to  ( **iterate and check it's attribute** ) . I am finding the easiest way to get it.

I would really appreciate your suggestions !

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code:

```
NodeList<Element> elements = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("input");
```

to get all of your inputs. Next step should be to iterate over the list and check the attributes with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
    if (elements.getItem(i).getAttribute("nature").equals("price")) {
        // found it
    }
}
```

a better way would be to use the attribute **id** instead of nature. In this case you get the element with:

```
Document.get().getElementById("price")
```

Alternative you can use [Errai](http://erraiframework.org/) where you can bind your widgets to native HTML.

Comment: If I have 3 elements having "price" attribute , but my page has many input elements() , I will iterate over all of them. I want to filter when getting Elements . I want to avoid iteration and checking elements these I want to get . When getting **NodeList** , I think I need to recast them as **Element elem = Element.as(node);**.

Comment: Would you like to say "it is not possible !" . If so please guide me the easiest way to get it. BTW , why not GWT support for that ? :)

Comment: Why are you trying to get the elements, insteed of using GWT widgets?

Comment: I am using DOM handler, and my input elements are not in same panel (I mean they are not in a flextable or not in same vertical panel).

Comment: Yes may be , Whoooo ! but I am very hard to insert this. Instead of this I should iterate and check element's attribute. I am with team-working.